# Mail template of 'Mail Template Editor' (ownCloud) does not read templates created

Tags: owncloud, univention-corporate-server

I have ownCloud running on a UCS.
When logging in as an admin on ownCloud you are able to add new users. When adding one ownCloud sends an auto-generated e-mail to the user. I was asking myself if it is possible to change the content of the mail and found out that there is an app called 'Mail Template Editor'. I installed it and was wondering why on ownCloud in settings/general there was a text which told me to add themes. After a long search I found a website where I followed these steps

```
mkdir /var/www/<owncloud install dir>/themes/<your theme dir>/settings

mkdir /var/www/<owncloud install dir>/themes/<your theme dir>/settings/templates

chown www-data. /var/www/<owncloud install dir>/themes/<your theme dir>/settings -R

chmod 766 /var/www/<owncloud install dir>/themes/<your theme dir>/settings/templates
```

It was now possible to use the MailTemplateEditor on ownCloud and I was trying it out. I was editing a 'new_user' template and created a user. I checked the mailbox of this user and now the **MAIN QUESTION** follows:

I received a german (since my owncloud is in german) mail where no template was used. I was trying to figure out if the mail template does not apply on non-english mails but I had no idea how to access the english ownCloud version. But the main question is: Can I edit this german version as well and how?

**EDIT:** is it probably possible to turn off the translation calls so it always sends my template mail? I am not that experienced in PHP/HTML to see where the call is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution of my problem which I do not think is the best option. I have not tried yet how it will work if I edit another mail template. If there is a better way please feel free to post it here.

I have read that it is not a good option to change the `owncloud/config/config.php` file and add the line `'theme => <mythemeDir>'` at the end since it should be done within the app itself. But I found no better way of doing so. Maybe I misunderstood something or rather I am not that involved with this topic but one page tells me not to edit it the other one does, both seemed to be from ownCloud itself so I was considering it up to date.